# Emacs console mode is buggy when using solarized theme in OSX

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

I use emacs in console mode and I want to use the solarized dark theme in both my terminal and within emacs.  I installed the theme and all the colors are working properly, but now emacs is malfunctioning.

The issues:

- Terminal window is not confined to emacs.  You can scroll up and see the terminal history from before emacs was started. Scrolling in general moves the terminal's view rather than moving the cursor. within emacs.
- Quitting emacs does not get rid of the content on the screen, it just adds a new line at the bottom with a terminal prompt but keeps the emacs view in the terminal history
- splitting the screen into multiple buffers (e.g. with C-x 3) causes two problems: the dividing boarder gets broken when a line is too long and carries over to the next line (on the new line the boarder is in the wrong column), and switching between buffers with C-x o will sometimes cause the visual representation of the cursor to become offset from where it should be (e.g. should at the beginning of line but is at the end of the line instead)
- General problems with displaying indentation, and other formatting
- Sometimes while editing text, unexpected things happen as if the display does not correspond to the contents of the file. E.g. getting an "end of file" error when trying to move down a line from the middle of the file, hitting backspace replaces one line with another, space and tab do nothing, etc.

Info:

- OS: OSX Yosemite
- Emacs version: 24.4.1
- Solarized installation:

```
git clone git://github.com/altercation/solarized.git
open solarized/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/Solarized\ Dark \ansi.terminal
git clone https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized.git
mv emacs-color-theme-solarized .emacs.d/themes
```

relevant section of .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/emacs-color-theme-solarized")                                                                                                          
(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)
```

EDIT: Solved (see answer)

Comment: Since some of this is visual you might want to link to a screenshot.

Comment: A lot of these problems sound like issues with your terminal emulator. Which terminal are you using? Also, you're not using Emacs remotely, via ssh for example, are you? If the connection is not great a lot of colors can cause lag.

Comment: Thank you both for your input.  I was able to solve the problem, as explained in the answer I just posted. 

@nanny FYI I am working locally and using terminal.app

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by going to terminal -> preferences -> Solarized Dark, then changing "Declare terminal as" from "ansi" to "xterm-256color".

Now everything works like it should.